# Vim insert mode changes the font defined in ~/.Xresources

Tags: vim, fonts, arch-linux, xterm, i3-window-manager

### Background

I am running Arch Linux with the i3 WM. I am trying to customize the font in Xterm by editing ~/.Xresources as every online resource online has told me to.

### What i have done

I add the following lines to .Xresources

```
 *xterm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono
 *xterm*faceSize: 10
```

Then in xterm i run

```
xrdb ~/.Xresources
```

Then i start a new xterm and the font has successfully changed.

### The Problem

I go to edit a document by opening it in vim. When i push 'i' to enter insert mode the whole font changes, it becomes larger and a completely different font face.

I have searched everywhere online but was unable to find anyone with a similar problem. I want to keep the same font face and size everywhere.

Comment: It could be a plug-in, (mis)using xterm's escape sequence for switching font-sizes.  I'd start vim without plugins and add them by one-by-one to isolate the problem.